# Strange transition_to behavior

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I've come across some unexpected behavior when using `transition_to` from a router.

What happens is that the route changes correctly but the `{{outlet}}` is not cleared.

I boiled down the example as much as possible [in this jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cayusi/8/edit).

I have a `authorize` and a `secret` resource, when jumping from the `secret` resource back to the `authorize` resource the contents of the `secrets` template (yellow) stay in place: [image]

My expectation would be that the `secrets` template disappears and the `authorize` template is rendered into the `{{outlet}}` instead.

Weirdly enough the ember inspector also doesn't pick up on it:
[image]

I am fairly new to ember, so my assumption is that I am doing something wrong, but this kind of looks like a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have bad HTML in your handlebars, mismatched tags is the biggest reason for this.

Your secret template has two opening div tags.